# producer-consumer program : should I change the value of a semaphore inside or outside the critical section?

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore, producer-consumer, critical-section

I'm writing a simple producer-consumer program which should be based on a fixed sized queue.

I'm implementing it using a list.

**My 2 questions are:**

1. In the following piece of code, I'm checking whether the list is empty or not in order to know if the consumer should and has something to consume.

My instructions are:
**Use a linked list + only one mutex and consumers should do a while of (is not empty..)**

so the consumer function I have wrote is:
*(meanwhile we were asked to write only the pseudo code)*

```
/*  start function: handler function of consumer:   */

    /*  while program is running */
    
        /*  while linked list is not empty: */
        
            /*  lock mutex - critical section entrance  */
            /*  pop the last element and save its data in a variable */
            /*  unlock mutex - critical section exit    */
             
           /* print the popped data */              

        /*  end of while is not empty   */
        
    /*  end of while    */

/*  end function    */
```

someone told me:

> - "you should not spend time in the critical section. you don't need to print things while being there. our goal in the critical section is
>   to exit it as fast as possible. do everything related with the data
>   structure, in this case, the list, inside the critical section and get
>   out of it and only then do the consuming, which in this case, is
>   printing out the data that was removed."

He told me that I have to check if the list is empty INSIDE the critical section because its an operation that directly related with the data structure.

My question is: Why? why can't I check if the list is empty and only then get inside the critical section?

This is my fixed code following his comments:

```
/*  start function: handler function of consumer:   */

/*  while program is running */

    /*  lock mutex - critical section entrance  */
    
    /*  while linked list is not empty: */
        /*  set global flag is_empty as 1   */
        /*  break   */
    /*  end of while is not empty   */
    
    /*  if is_empty: */
        /*  pop from the back of the list and save the popped data  */
    /*  end if      */
    
    /*  unlock mutex - critical section exit    */
    
    /*  consume - print popped data */
    /*  set is_empty as 0   */
    
  /*    end of while    */

/*  end function    */
```

**and my 2nd question is:**

If we work with semaphores, should we change their values inside or outside the critical section and why?

for example, in the following piece of code:

```
/*  start function: handler function of a producer: */

/*  while program is running:   */

    /*  decrement the value of the semaphore num_of_empty_bins  */
    /*  lock mutex_producer - critical section entrance */
    /*  enqueue data    */
    /*  increment the value of the semaphore num_of_full_bins   */
    /*  unlock mutex_producer - critical section exit   */
    
  /*    end of while    */

/*  end function    */
```

as you can see there are increment & decrement functions INSIDE the critical section.
Originally, I wrote it outside the section, before and after the mutex lock.
But my friend told me that he thinks it should be after and before the lock/unlock.

We can't find an answer for it anywhere, so we don't know if there is a difference or reason to do it .

And should these increment/decrement operations must be atomic even if it's inside the critical section? Or they should be atomic only if there are outside the section?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using 'real' OS-supported semaphores, the signals/waits should be outside the critical section and, in that case, there is no need to check the list contents at all at the consumer, (unbounded list), or producer/consumer, (bounded list, as you have).

Comment: @MartinJames what are 'real' OS-supported semaphores? i'm aware only of SV and Posix semaphores and these are the ones I am talking about.

Comment: Yup, they are fine.  There are 'examples' of user-space 'semaphore' code about that are, well, not semaphores:(   A thread must be able to efficiently block on an empty semaphore, and only the OS kernel can provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Threads and data races (cppreference.com)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races)

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless either
>
> - both conflicting evaluations are [atomic operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic)
> - one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see [memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order))
>
> If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined.

**Your first question:** "Why? why can't I check if the list is empty and only then get inside the critical section?"

Another thread could modify the state of the list before you enter the critical section. You believe the list is empty, but in fact it is not (or vice versa). Therefore, every thread has to enter the critical section before any read or write of a shared variable.

**Second question:**

Same goes here. As long as you don't use atomic data types, entering the critical section is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Why? why can't I check if the list is empty and only then get inside the critical section?

Because non-atomic access to shared variables, such as your list and its members, must be performed only subject to synchronization measures sufficient to prevent accesses by multiple threads at the same time.  That is a strictly stronger constraint than limiting access to critical sections.  One must prevent, for example, one thread accessing a shared object from one critical section while a different thread accesses the same shared object from a different critical section.

If this synchronization requirement is not fulfilled then program behavior is undefined. In practice, that undefinedness can manifest as threads not seeing each others' updates, data corruption, and other very real and impactful problems.  These tend also to be very difficult to debug, so it pays to attend carefully to proper synchronization from the beginning.

> If we work with semaphores, should we change their values inside or outside the critical section and why?

Semaphores are synchronization objects that can and often do serve as mutexes. They are therefore irrelevant to the particular task you described, in which I would take using a semaphore in addition to the mutex to be in violation at least of the spirit of the "only one mutex" constraint.  If you don't want it for its synchronization properties then a plain integer can serve the same purposes.

With that said, if you did add a semaphore to your program then the main concern would be whether multiple threads using the mutex and semaphore constituted a deadlock risk.  You should be able to ensure that they do not by following the general principle that every thread that intends to hold a given pair of locks at the same time must acquire them in the same relative order.  Both locking the mutex and decrementing the semaphore once would count as acquiring a lock.  You should be able to choose either order, as long as you are consistent.  In particular, manipulating a semaphore does not inherently require the protection of a different synchronization object.

> And should these increment/decrement operations must be atomic even if it's inside the critical section? Or they should be atomic only if there are outside the section?

Increment and decrement operations on shared variables do not need to be atomic if they are (everywhere) properly synchronized, as described above.  Under some circumstances, it is possible to substitute atomic modifications without other synchronization, but this needs to be considered in light of the larger context.  Although an atomic modification outside any critical section might be ok in itself, it might nevertheless produce or allow unwanted program behaviors.